# 500 Server Error on posting Javascript variable to external Laravel Application(PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

Of course there are many threads related posting javascript variables to external Laravel(PHP) file.Tried almost every answer given by community finally ended up with this server 500 on my javascript console.

Let explain clearly:
I am using XAMMP for local development and two different independent directories namely "A" and "B"."A" is pure javascript file "B" is Laravel(PHP). Now i am posting variable of "A" to controller function of "B".

"A" -->On JS Side

```
var variableValue='abc';

$.post('http://localhost/B/public/api/tfs', {variable:variableValue});
```

"B"--->External Laravel Function side

```
public function index()
{
 $variable =Input::get('destinationLatitude');
  return json_encode($variable);
```

}

On "B" routes

```
Route::resource('tfs', 'FtsController', 
        array('except' => array('create', 'edit', 'update')));
```

-->I tried with POST instead of resource but Invain.

After trying many i am getting server 500 internal server error.I worked on `http.conf` and `.htaccess` files also no use.
So,any one help me please in posting javascript variable to laravel controller function.

Note:I don't want to include `<script>A.js</script>` on "B",because will not access to it later. So,AJAX is the only way I think of.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change `$variable =Input::get('variableValue');` to

`$variable =Input::get('variable');`

You're passing in `variableValue` AS `variable` here:

```
$.post('http://localhost/B/public/api/tfs', {variable:variableValue});
```

When I do things like this, I write something like this:

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/api/test', 'TestController@start');
```

**TestController.php**

```
<?php

class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function start(){
        $variable = Input::get('variable');
        return json_encode($variable);
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$.post('/api/test', {variable:variableValue});
```

Comment: same 500 internal server error , I followed your modifications but.. invain.

Comment: @user3165034 Can you manually push in data to the controller and run it to see if it works?

Comment: Yeah..Manually push in data is working ..I used Postman google chrome Addon for this and my laravel application is catching the variable and showing the success results.

Comment: @user3165034 Okay, and you're sure that the ajax request is being sent? When does that error pop up? In the web browser console?

Comment: Ahh..Finally the server error 500 was solver @Gustaf thank you for this but my ajax post reqest is appending the query parameters to the post URL.. $.post('http://localhost/applo/public/api/tfs', {'variable':'csdc'}); .... and also tried $.post('http://localhost/applo/public/api/tfs', {variabl':'csdc'}); and also in place of 'csdc' tried with defined variable also.. But when I manually pass query parameters to the URL as /api/tfs?variable=csdc it was working.So,I think problem was on Ajax POST side?? Can you help me please

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it, but don't use the localhost-url in the post method. If you want to run that live, then you have to change all those URLs. "/api/tfsjs" works